# TextField returning blank

Tags: flutter

I have, which is probably a simple error. I'm using a TextField and created a custom widget.

```
    class NoteField extends StatefulWidget {
  NoteField({Key? key, required this.n}) : super(key: key);
  String n;

  @override
  State<NoteField> createState() => _NoteFieldState();
}

class _NoteFieldState extends State<NoteField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      maxLength: 40,
      onChanged: (String value) {
        widget.n = value;
        print(widget.n);
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        )),
        hintText: 'Enter a label for your visit',
      ),
    );
  }
```

So when I use this widget, I've created a String _note and I pass this to the widget.

```
NoteField(n: _note),
```

However, I'm getting blank. When I type I can see `n` updating from the print statement but when I try and print _note when I press a button, it's showing as blank.

Comment: Please add the button script too

Comment: nothing fancy in there, just printing it out. print(_note);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a string pass the TextEditingController to the class.

```
class NoteField extends StatefulWidget {
  NoteField({Key? key, required this.n}) : super(key: key);
  TextEditingController n;

  @override
  State<NoteField> createState() => _NoteFieldState();
}

class _NoteFieldState extends State<NoteField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: n,
      maxLength: 40,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        )),
        hintText: 'Enter a label for your visit',
      ),
    );
  }
```

Use

```
print(controller.text);
```

From the other classs. Here controller is the TextEditingController that you passed to the NoteField class

Comment: Think there is a little mistake in the `widget.n = value;` line as n is now a `TextEditindController` and you assign a `String`. It's not necessary to keep the onChange, right ?

Comment: Sorry i missed it. Edited the answer now

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `TextEditingController` to keep the state of your values and retrieve it in parents widget.

There is multiple solution to manage the state, one of them using setState and keys is the following:

You assign a GlobalKey to retrieve your child stateful widget. You create a `TextEditingController` that manages the initial value and that will hold your textfield data.
Finally you use the key to access the state of your child widget.

```
class TextFieldPage extends StatelessWidget {
  TextFieldPage({super.key});

  final GlobalKey<NoteFieldState> noteFieldKey = GlobalKey<NoteFieldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          NoteField(
            key: noteFieldKey,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(noteFieldKey.currentState!.controller!.text);
              },
              child: Text('Print textfield value')),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class NoteField extends StatefulWidget {
  const NoteField({Key? key, this.initialString}) : super(key: key);
  final String? initialString;

  @override
  State<NoteField> createState() => NoteFieldState();
}

class NoteFieldState extends State<NoteField> {
  late TextEditingController? controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialString);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      maxLength: 40,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        )),
        hintText: 'Enter a label for your visit',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can always pass a callback to your widget to update the value you are passing to the TextField widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';

class TextFieldPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TextFieldPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextFieldPage> createState() => _TextFieldPageState();
}

class _TextFieldPageState extends State<TextFieldPage> {
  String data = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          NoteField(
              callback: (value) => setState(() => data = value)),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(data);
              },
              child: Text('Print textfield value')),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class NoteField extends StatefulWidget {
  const NoteField({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);
  final Function callback;

  @override
  State<NoteField> createState() => NoteFieldState();
}

class NoteFieldState extends State<NoteField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (value) => widget.callback(value),
      maxLength: 40,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        )),
        hintText: 'Enter a label for your visit',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems an over elaborate solution for what I need. Everything is working fine other than I want to transfer the contents of n to _note. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: Updated with another approach if you prefer it this way, you update the value you pass to the child directly @LeeCasey

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a TextEditingController or in your onChanged you need to wrap the assignment in a

```
SetState(() {
 widget.n = value
})
```

Comment: Same issue, don't think it's a state issue.

Comment: so are you passing values to this widget and wanting to prefill the text field, or passing the text field value back up?

Comment: I pass an empty string to the widget (_note) I then want it to populate the string upon editing then print it out when I press the button. For some reason _note isn't being populated or its being reinitialised somehow.

Comment: what if, instead of passing the value to the widget you pass in the onChanged function. That way the variable is not being passed around, and the TextField would be triggering on function of the Widget above scope.

Side note, i have found the native textfield in flutter not very enjoyable for these kind of reasons, i have switched to the ReactiveForms package on pub.dev, it is a bit easier to manage, since your parent can have the formgroup and you can pass formcontrols around.